# mongoDb process match phase incorrectly

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.test2.aggregate([     
    {$addFields:        { month: {$month: '$date'}     }} ,
    {$match: {month:{$gte:6}, month: {$lte:8}}} 
])
```

and this one returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040063b2e9243afa277c0"), "date" : ISODate("1990-08-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040093b2e9243afa277c1"), "date" : ISODate("1990-07-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040133b2e9243afa277c2"), "date" : ISODate("1990-06-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980401a3b2e9243afa277c3"), "date" : ISODate("1990-05-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040203b2e9243afa277c4"), "date" : ISODate("1990-04-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040243b2e9243afa277c5"), "date" : ISODate("1990-03-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598040273b2e9243afa277c6"), "date" : ISODate("1990-02-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980402c3b2e9243afa277c7"), "date" : ISODate("1990-01-25T00:00:00Z"), "month" : 1 }
```

But this result is incorrrect from my point of view.

Dates with months 1-5 should not be in result.

What do I wrong ?

Comment: The query is wrong. You are **overwriting** `"month"`. Should be `{$match: {month:{$gte:6, $lte:8 } }`. Since you overwrite the only condition considered is `$lte: 8` since it was the last mentioned, as demonstrated in the results.

Comment: Can I again highlight that ["since you only just recently completed a course"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416875/how-to-save-file-less-than-16-mb-using-mongo-shell) then maybe [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) should be your **first** port of call, rather than immediately posting here. Actually taking the time to read documentation will solve most of your issues. That particular "range query" is mentioned several times throughout the official sources. So it's hard to get it wrong when you actually read the manual.

Comment: @Neil Lunn thanks for answer

Comment: Well I really should point out that you are doing things completely wrong. Instead of wasting CPU and I/O on "projection" you should in fact simply be supplying the "range": i.e `{ "$match": { "date": { "$gte": new Date("1990-06-01"), "$lt": new Date("1990-09-01") } } }`. And if you really did want "month" independent of the year, then store it in the document instead. Calculating values like this is extremely costly in real world scenarios.

Comment: @Neil Lunn  I need to return people with birthday in summer

Comment: Store the month and day as separate numeric fields. Calculations are not efficient in any database.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, Thanks for your advice. I will it bear in mind. I am in process of course and I am not sure that I need to save it to separated fields, but if I wiuld have problems with performance - I will apply your advice

Comment: Okay fine. Just thought [I might know a little about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongodb/topusers) and therefore offer you some practical advise based on my experience. But maybe you should rather listen to a response of someone more experienced than myself.

Comment: @Neil Lunn I am sure you are very experienced but I also think that I should encounter issues in process of education and resolve it step by step